# Unknown WiFi network showing up on my phone

Tags: wifi

I have a WiFi network showing up on my phone: "H2O-e04f43b9ec36". My neighbors are a significant distance away and I am curious as to what is giving it off as I’m in the middle of an ugly separation.

[image]

Comment: The name of a wlan access point alone says nothing about what is exactly going on here since not enough context is known. It might be some portable wlan router offer by H2O Wireless though, like [this one](https://www.h2obolt.com/). But it is unknown why this shows up in your network. Anyway, an unkown WLAN hotspot nearby does not mean a __information security__ issue by itself, i.e. off-topic.

Comment: @Kate Why is *your* wifi network not in that list?

Comment: @Kate While this is not the right place to try to figure out what the device might be, the linked duplicate question has many options for tracking down the signal. Some are for company networks, but many answers cover general situations.

Comment: Yes, that is my primary question drewbenn. My WiFi signal was disconnected, as I was trying to unplug any systems (such as a new printer and wireless speaker) that I thought might be associated with the signal. Thank you everyone for your help! -Kate